# Changing theme color of the webpage

Tags: css, angularjs

I want to change three fields of webpage(i.e. header, menu, footer) with three different colors after clicking on a single button. If i use onclick() function it only change only field color or it changes all area with same color.

```
<div ng-style="myStyle" class="header">
<h1 style="color:white;padding:20px;">Header</h1>
</div>enter code here`

<div class="menu" ng-style=""">

<br><br><br>
<h2 style="color:white;margin-left:20px">Menu</h2>
<br>
<form class="n1">
<p style="color:white;"><b>Choose any color to change the <br/>theme of your website.</b></p><br/>
<input class="n2" type="button" value="Red" ng-click="myStyle={background:'red'}"><br><br>
  <input class="n3" type="button" value="Green" ng-click="myStyle={background:'green'}"><br><br>

  <input class="n4" type="button" value="Yellow" ng-click="myStyle={background:'yellow'}"><br><br>
  <input class="n5" type="button" value="Lime" ng-click="myStyle={background:'lime'}"><br><br>
  <input class="n6" type="button" value="Magenta" ng-click="myStyle={background:'magenta'}"><br>
 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app=''>
<div ng-style="myStyle.header" class="header">
  <h1 style="color:white;padding:20px;">Header</h1>
</div>enter code here

<div class="menu" ng-style='myStyle.body'>


  <h2 style="color:white;margin-left:20px">Menu</h2>
  <br>
  <form class="n1">
    <p style="color:white;"><b>Choose any color to change the <br/>theme of your website.</b>
    </p>
    <br/>
    <input class="n2" type="button" value="Red" ng-click="myStyle={header: {background:'red'}, body: {background:'maroon'}}">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input class="n3" type="button" value="Green" ng-click="myStyle={header: {background:'green'}, body: {background:'darkgreen'}}">
    <br>
    <br>

    <input class="n4" type="button" value="Yellow" ng-click="myStyle={header: {background:'yellow'}, body: {background:'orange'}}">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input class="n5" type="button" value="Lime" ng-click="myStyle={header: {background:'red'}, body: {background:'pink'}}">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </form>
</div>
  </body>
```

Here is a working snippet where all of the styles are changing. You hadn't added an `ng-app`, thereby no scope was provided. Is this what you want? Or was it something else? The question is a little ambiguous.

**Update**

If you want different colors for different elements, just use nested objects like so:

```
{
 header: 
   {
     background:'red'
   }, 
 body: {
     background:'maroon'
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I know the question is quite ambiguous. I have added ng-app. and it's working just like the code you provided. but, as you can see if I click on the red button it changes all the section in red color. now, the all I want is to change header part in different color(may be red) and the menu section in different color(light red). and do the same task on every click of the button on their formats of color.header should be actual color and menu would be their light(faded) color.